# Get Connected App used for authentication in apex code

Tags: apex, connected-apps

I created connected apps for various integrated systems in our landscape, that use custom developed REST endpoints to access specific data from our salesforce org.

I have separate apps per system, and since I have a logging application that logs any calls to my API with some meta-data (duration, execution start/end timestamps, outcomes, errors, used ressource path, etc), I would like to also log the connected app that was used to authenticate.

I already searched the Auth Namespace but could not find any method to retrieve the `ConnectedAppId`, is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You can query connected app information with the help of following query:

`Select Name, Id From ConnectedApplication`

[image: ConnectedApplication]

You can extend [Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_ConnectedAppPlugin.htm) to log through which connected app you performed authentication.

Here is sample code:

```
global with sharing class TestConnectedAppPlugin extends Auth.ConnectedAppPlugin {

    global override boolean authorize(Id userId, Id connectedAppId, boolean isAdminApproved) {

    }
}
```

You need to add this class in the Edit Policies section of Connected app.

[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78444/discussion-between-mr-frodo-and-j-lietzau).